# Segmentation fault in implementating DFS in C++

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

I have an implementation of graph traversal in C++. I tried to debug and fix it but it didn't work. It seems my program crashed because there's something wrong with my adjacent list in the graph and I tried to access the memory that I haven't initialized. Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance.

Graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include <list>
#include <vector>

class Graph {
    int vertex;
    bool isDirected;
    std::vector<std::list<int>> adjList;
public:
    Graph(int vertex = 10, bool isDirected = false)
        : vertex(vertex), isDirected(isDirected) {
        adjList.resize(vertex);
    }
    void addEdge(int src, int dest) {
        adjList[src].push_back(dest);
        if (!isDirected) adjList[dest].push_back(src);
    }

    int getVertex() const { return this->vertex; }
    std::vector<std::list<int>> getAdjList() const { return this->adjList; }
};

#endif /* GRAPH_H */
```

Traverse.h

```
#ifndef TRAVERSE_H
#define TRAVERSE_H

#include "Graph.h"
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

class Traverse {
    std::deque<bool> visited;
public:
    Traverse(Graph graph) { visited.assign(graph.getVertex(), false); }
    void DFS(Graph graph, int parentVertex) {
        visited[parentVertex] = true;
        std::cout << parentVertex << std::endl;

        // Segmentation fault here
        for (auto childVertex : graph.getAdjList().at(parentVertex))
            if (visited.at(childVertex) == false) DFS(graph, childVertex);
    }
};
#endif /* TRAVERSE_H */
```

graph.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Traverse.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Graph graph(5, true);
    graph.addEdge(1, 2);
    graph.addEdge(1, 3);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3);
    graph.addEdge(1, 4);

    Traverse traverse(graph);
    traverse.DFS(graph, 1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Compiled and ran on my machine, no seg fault.  Generated a lot of warnings.

Comment: @Eljay Hows that possible? Godbolt is returning error code 255 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aa2NX_

Comment: Two things to look for: 1) Make sure all of your vector accesses are within bounds.  2) `std::vector<std::list<int>> getAdjList() const { return this->adjList; }` -- Make sure your intent is to return the actual list, and not a copy of the list.  If it's the actual list, this should be returning a reference, not a copy.

Comment: @borievka • undefined behavior can appear to work as expected.  What works in a non-optimized build may fail in an optimized build -- or vice versa.  What seg faults on one platform may appear to work correctly on another.  One of the many joys of C++.

Comment: unrelated: Graph::vertex should be the same as `Graph::adjList::size`. You should be able to eliminate it and the possibility for the two to get out of sync and wreck havoc. `std::list` can be painfully slow. You sure you want a `list` here and not another `vector`?

Comment: @user4581301 Because I want a vector of lists, not a matrix for graph representation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment stated, you are returning copies of the adjacency list instead of the actual adjacency list.  That becomes an issue here:

`for (auto childVertex : graph.getAdjList().at(parentVertex))`

Since a local copy is returned, the iterator becomes invalid when iterating to the next element.

One fix is to change your `getAdjList()` function to return a reference:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>>& getAdjList() { return this->adjList; }
```